# Does threads in a process stop If a thread in the process makes swap by page fault on multi processor environment?

Tags: linux

I'm making threads through Pthread libray provided by glibc on the multiprocessor environment.
There are two groups of thread, which one group resides on core1, and the other does on core2.
I'm trying to accomplish real-time performance through this but i wonder if a thread on core1 makes swap operation by page-fault it results in making whole threads in the process stop by kswapd which does swap operation?